# Get IP of the Author only

Tags: 7, entities

I use this solution for now which works great: It's with Computed fields, and I use this line: $`entity_field[0]['value'] = ip_address();`

So basically what it does, it's when a user submits a new node, it also attach his IP address to the node, which is great.

The problem is that if another user decides to edit the node, the IP field is being updated with the editors IP. Which is bad.

The IP should be printed only of the author of the node. And no matter how many other IPs edits the node, those should be ignored.

So, I was thinking maybe there was possible to do this by editing the PHP line or am I looking in wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use [Rules](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=drupal%20rules) on new content creation then run the php code.

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

EDIT:

- Enable the module 'PHP Filter'
- In Rules, use the 'After Saving New Content' React on Type - this will trigger each time content is published for the first time
- Optionally, add a condition Restrict by Type, choose the content type in which you want this to appear
- Add a new action 'PHP: Execute custom php code' with your own code

Answer (score 0):

Use the [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7), it respond to creation of a new node, not when you edit it.

```
function YOURMODULENAME_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'nodetype') {
    // Action
  }
}
```

Greetings.